# Multi module project in gradle fails compile when

Tags: java, gradle, multi-module

I am using gradle 5.1.1 & have the following configuration in my multi module project

`settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'multi-module-test'

include 'mock-api', 'mock-impl'
```

`build.gradle`

```
group 'com.acme'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  sourceCompatibility = 1.8

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

project(':mock-impl') {
  dependencies {
    // this fails
    // api project(':mock-api')

    // this succeeds
    implementation project(':mock-api')
  }
}
```

For some strange reason if I use `api` configuration, the build fails with this reason

`Could not find method api() for arguments [project ':mock-api'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

But it does not fail when I use `implementation` configuration

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face this problem because you don't use `java-library` plugin. Have a look at the gradle docs, it says;

> The key difference between the standard Java plugin and the Java
>   Library plugin is that the latter introduces the concept of an API
>   exposed to consumers.

So try including;

```
 plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}
```

Reference: 
https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#header